# PHP: When using javascript in a html file I could assign var mythis=this in the global scope. Is there a similiar way in PHP?

Tags: php, class, this, global, parent

When using javascript in a html file I could assign `var mythis=this` in the global scope. Is there a similiar way in PHP?

```
<html><head>
<script> var mythis= this;</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

Is this possible in php,too?

```
<?php
$mythis = ....????

// or in a function or class?

function a() { $t = ....????; } // looking for global's $this


?>
```

Edit: Without using namespace. However they work.

Answer (score 1):

$this in PHP is a pseudo variable, when methods are called in the context of an object, a reference to the calling object. For example:

```
<?php
class A{
    private $a = 1;

    public function getA(){
        return $this->a;
    }
}?>
```